# Trouble Understanding Seemingly Simple Property of the Cantor Ternary Space

Tags: general-topology

In Cullen's *Introduction to General Topology* the very first result involving the Cantor Ternary Space (CTS) is that no single point is open. I'll detail the proof below, but first would like to state my innate disbelief of this result: the product topology defines open sets as those products which are of all open sets... Is every sequence of the Cantor set not just the infinite product of open sets from the discrete space N2={0,1}? This seems to completely contradict the definition of the product topology as far as I can see, but clearly I'm missing something. Here's the proof as stated in the text:

By definition of the product topology any base element $U^*$ is $\Pi_{i=1}^\infty U_i$, where $U_i$ is open in $Y_i=\{0,1\}$ in $U_i=Y_i$ for $i>k\in\mathbb{N}$. Hence for any point in the CTS denoted by $(x_1,x_2,x_3,...,x_i,...)$, no set containing this one point contains a base element, since $\{x_{k+1}\}$ does not contain $Y_{k+1}$. Hence, $\Pi_{i=1}^\infty \{x_i\}$ does not contain $U^*$, so no one point set is open.

Perhaps it's the notation that's confusing me? As far as I can tell from searching for the past thirty minutes, this is the only source that addresses this specific result... I simply can't find an explanation that makes sense.

Comment: Maybe what you are missing is that, in the product topology, open sets are rarer than you think. (See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_topology , the base consists of $\prod_{i\in\mathbb N} U_i$ where $U_i$ is open in $\{0,1\}$ and *only finitely many $U_i$'s are $\ne\{0,1\}$*). Without the last condition, any subset of CTS would be open - i.e. the topology would be discrete. Another way to look at this is that the CTS is homeomorphic to Cantor set (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set), which you can visualise on the real line,

Comment: @StinkingBishop This should be an official answer.

Comment: @StinkingBishop oh, I see. That last condition isn't included in the "box topology", which I've mistakenly taken as the topology for any product space. Thanks!

Comment: Yep, these two topologies match for finite products but not for infinite products.

Comment: The product topology is sometimes called the Tychonoff product topology to avoid confusion, especially because some people call the box topology the "box product topology".

Comment: The box topology seems like a "natural" generalization to infinite products. But the product topology has been extremely useful for a long list of important results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe what you are missing is that, in the product topology, open sets are rarer than you think. (See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_topology , the base consists of $\prod_{i\in\mathbb N}U_i$ where $U_i$ is open in $\{0,1\}$ and *only finitely many $U_i$'s are $\ne\{0,1\}$*). Without the last condition, any subset of CTS would be open - i.e. the topology would be discrete. Another way to look at this is that the CTS is homeomorphic to Cantor set (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set), which you can visualise on the real line